# Touch events not triggered on element edges in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, safari

On touch devices the following events are triggered when touching an element:

- touchstart
- touchend
- mouseenter
- mousedown
- mouseup
- click

The mouseenter, mousedown, mouseup and click events are emulated by the touchend event. If you want to disable this emulation of mouse events, preventDefault() can be used.

But if in iOS Safari I touch the edges of an element the following events are triggered:

- mouseenter
- mousedown
- mouseup
- click

Somehow the touch events are not triggered on the edges and because of this I also can't use preventDefault() to stop the emulation of the mouse events.

The problem occurs on both iPhone as iPad.

I searched Stack Overflow and Google, but I can't find anything about this. No bugs and no solutions. Does anybody know if this is a known bug in Safari?

I created the most basic code to reproduce this error in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7536d9sf/1/):

HTML:

```
<div id="element"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#element {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function handler(event) {
  const log = document.getElementById('log');
  
  log.innerHTML = `${event.type}<br />${log.innerHTML}`;
}

const element = document.getElementById('element');

element.addEventListener('mouseenter', handler);
element.addEventListener('mouseleave', handler);
element.addEventListener('mousedown', handler);
element.addEventListener('mouseup', handler);
element.addEventListener('click', handler);
element.addEventListener('focus', handler);
element.addEventListener('blur', handler);
element.addEventListener('touchstart', handler);
element.addEventListener('touchend', handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the event listener to the outermost element, the html tag.

See more:
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php

Comment: That would only trigger the events on every single html element and whitespace. That's not what I'm looking for. I want to do effects on a single element based on touchstart and touchend events. But these events are not triggered when the element is touched on the inside edge of that element.